# After update to Xcode 11 all views in my iOS 11 apps are misplaced

Tags: xcode, view, size, width

I updated Xcode to version 11 and I wanted to update my apps to iOS 13 version. After updating I tried to open my projects (iOS 11) and... all views are misplaced, are positioned in the middle of view controllers, width and height are 712x728 (before it it was normal 1024x768) etc. Options for manual positioning is off, i tried ScaletoFill etc. but without effect. 
How can I correct it? What is the best way?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

See if this works: Select the View Controller. In the Attributes Inspector change "Presentation" from "Automatic" to "Full screen".
This should resize your top View - or at least give you the option to edit it.